# Algolia, Show results when one word match

Tags: algolia

I don't know if I have a problem with my configuration or if there is something else to do but when I search "word1" I get some results, and "word1 word2" I don't get any.
"word2" my be any type of word (like "kfuzefzuefd"), it's normal that I don't get results with it, but i'd like to show the results from "word1".

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve that, you can use the [removeWordsIfNoResults](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/parameters/removeWordsIfNoResults/#removewordsifnoresults) parameter in order to get results for `word1` in case `word1 word2` gives no results.

You can modify this parameter in your dashboard if you go to `Indices` -> `Ranking tab` -> `Remove words if no results` if you scroll at the bottom in the Query Expansion section.